# How to provide example for XML parameter in swagger

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I am using `Swashbuckle 5.6.0` and `Swashbuckle.Examples.3.5.1` to document a WebApi2 project.  I have an action which consumes an XML body and returns a text response.  I want the documentation to include an example of the XML input - e.g. `<SampleXml><!-- example XML --></SampleXml>`.

My swagger output is below, except that for the purposes of this question I have added the content-type `application/json` to the `comsumes`  property.  In reality, I only want to allow `application/xml` and `text/xml`.

When I view this with Swagger, I see:

- When parameter content type `application/xml` is selected, I get a generated XML example with my model name, i.e. `<XmlModel></XmlModel>`.
- When parameter content type `application/json` is selected, I get my desired example input `<SampleXml><!-- example XML --></SampleXml>`.

How can I get the example input while parameter content type `application/xml` is selected?

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "Sample"
  },
  "host": "localhost:63434",
  "schemes": [
    "http"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/sampleXml/": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "xmlSample"
        ],
        "summary": "XML sample.",
        "description": "Post XML sample",
        "operationId": "Xml_Post",
        "consumes": [
          "application/xml",
          "application/json",
          "text/xml",
        ],
        "produces": [
          "text/plain"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "xmlContent",
            "in": "body",
            "description": "The content of the XML document.",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/XmlModel"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "XmlModel": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {},
      "example": "<SampleXml><!-- example XML --></SampleXml>"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in the SwaggerUI, I tested your swagger.json on the latest and the issue still present:
http://nhc-noaa.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?url=http://nhc-noaa.azurewebsites.net/joe2_swagger.json&filter=xmlSample

Answer (score 2):

To change the root XML tag from `<XmlModel>` to `<SampleXml>`, add [`xml.name`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-xmlName) to your schema definition:

```javascript
  "definitions": {
    "XmlModel": {
      "type": "object",
      "xml": {
         "name": "SampleXml"
      }
    }
  }
```

This will produce the following sample XML in Swagger UI:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleXml>
</SampleXml>
```

And if you add property definitions:

```javascript
  "definitions": {
    "XmlModel": {
      "type": "object",
      "xml": {
         "name": "SampleXml"
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "example": 7,
          "xml": {
            "attribute": true
          }
        },
        "foo": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

your XML example will include the corresponding elements:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleXml id="7">
    <foo>bar</foo>
</SampleXml>
```

However, if you want the literal string `<SampleXml><!-- example XML --></SampleXml>` containing a `&lt;!-- comment --&gt;`, it's not possible AFAIK.

**Update:** Swagger UI supports using literal XML strings only in response examples:

```javascript
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "OK",
    "schema": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "examples": {
      "application/xml": "<SampleXml><!-- example XML --></SampleXml>"
    }
  }
}
```

but not in request body examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What I want is a literal XML string - the string doesn't contain a comment, but needs to match an application -specific schema which I haven't shown as it's not relevant to the question.  My objective is to be able to smoke test the API from the Swagger UI by copying example XML.