# Accepting body with generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a web API that accepts a custom object. This works when someone does a `POST` request in `JSON` format. But now I have someone asking if they can post in `XML`, from my understanding this shouldn't be an issue. However, the body is always `null` in my Controller.

```cs
public IHttpActionResult SomeMethod([FromBody] StoreModel<object> obj) {
    // ... Code
}
```

The model looks like this:

```cs
public class StoreModel<T> {
    public T MetaData { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Swagger suggests the following JSON input:

```json
{
  "metaData": {},
  "name": "string"
}
```

but for XML it says this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StoreModel[Object]>
  <!-- invalid XML -->
  <name>string</name>
</StoreModel[Object]>
```

I tried posting with variations of the swagger suggestion, but nothing seems to be accepted

So I would think some additional configuration is needed?

Comment: well, use you dynamic for that, but either using dynamic or list of `object` is a wrong approach.

For example: public IHttpActionResult SomeMethod(dynamic obj) {
    // ... Code
}

Comment: Using a generic with type of `object` seems like a terrible idea here anyway. Why not just make the `MetaData` property of type `object`? That's still not a great option, and I'd prefer to be more specific about the data being posted. Is it really generic? Or could you use a `Dictionary` instead?

Comment: you have to show the code that you are using to call this API

Comment: @Serge I just use swagger

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these 2 URLs:

- [Issue with sending XML to Web Api via http Post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424559/issue-with-sending-xml-to-web-api-via-http-post-request). Here notice at:

`([FromBody]XElement xml)`

- [How to provide example for XML parameter in swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906767/how-to-provide-example-for-xml-parameter-in-swagger)